# how to check if the variable exists in multiple datasets. i need output varname and dataset name

Tags: sas

how to check if the variable exists in multiple  dataset or not.

I need ouput like this.

[image]

kindly help.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Define multiple data sets, is it two or ore? If it's two you can use PROC COMPARE. Otherwise, try either of these to get you started: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/e0b98c4627aa31a567e5 or likely this one https://gist.github.com/statgeek/3b57ae085d9f7a36a2d95c15f04e72e6

Comment: Please review the guidelines on how to post a question here [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SASjs [macrocore](https://github.com/sasjs/core) library has a [macro](https://github.com/sasjs/core/blob/main/base/mp_searchcols.sas) that lets you search one or more libraries for one or more columns, and you can use it as follows:

```
/* compile macro */
filename mc url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasjs/core/main/base/mp_searchcols.sas";
%inc mc;

/* execute */
%mp_searchcols(libs=sashelp work, cols=name sex age)
```

[image]
Disclaimer - I wrote it.

Comment: Nice repository... just combed through it for a few minutes and already picked up some tips!  Will definitely go through it in more detail and am hoping to contribute once I get some time.

Comment: That would be great!